# Learn Python the hard way Exercise 13 (Import) no response in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm a beginner, learning python with the book "Learn Python the hard way"
Exercise 13 is about importing. This is the code I am meant to run through powershell.

```
from sys import argv
# read the WYSS section for how to run this
script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

In windows powershell I am typing:

```
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

I am getting no errors, nothing at all.

I am writing the code in Notepad++ and the file name is `ex13.py`

Comment: For me everything work fine, what python version are u using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.9

Comment: Does it work if you provide a rooted path to the file (eg. `python C:\lpthw\ex13\ex13.py first 2nd 3rd`)?

Comment: Are you sure that your python is in the PATH? Do other scripts work fine? just try: print("Hello world!")

Comment: It works with the file path! Thank you! Is there a way not to have to write the file path as well?

Comment: Other scripts such as print("Hello world!") work without the file path

Comment: When you launch `python.exe`, it inherits it's working directory from the parent process (`powershell.exe`), and that's what it uses to resolve relative file paths. PowerShell does _not_ update it's working directory when you change location _within_ PowerShell, hence the discrepancy (some files can be resolved relatively, some can't). `python "$PWD\ex13.py" ...` should do